# implement custom keycloak form authenticator?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-spi

so resently I am trying to implement an authentication service using spring boot and keycloak as. IAM tool ,
my login "get token" functionality could happen by two way, either by phone and password or email and password ,
i have done some digging and end up with implementing a custom authenticator as a solution,
i have done also some digging for implementation:
the code goes like below:

```
public class GsmAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm implements Authenticator {
    public static final String CONFIG_EXTERNAL_APP_URL = "external-application-url";
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GsmAuthenticator.class);

    public GsmAuthenticator() {
         logger.info("GSM authenticator has been created");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateUserAndPassword(AuthenticationFlowContext context, MultivaluedMap<String, String> inputData) {

        if (context.getAuthenticatorConfig().getConfig().get(CONFIG_EXTERNAL_APP_URL) == null){

            logger.error("get u  mother fucker ");
            return true;
        }

//        return super.validateUserAndPassword(context, inputData);
        String username = inputData.getFirst(AuthenticationManager.FORM_USERNAME).toString();
        logger.info("User name is: {}",username);
        if (username == null) {
            context.getEvent().error(Errors.USER_NOT_FOUND);
            Response challengeResponse = challenge(context, Messages.INVALID_USER);
            context.failureChallenge(AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER, challengeResponse);
            logger.error("Empty username");
            return false;
        }


        username = username.trim();
        logger.info("Username: {}",username);
        context.getEvent().detail(Details.USERNAME, username);
        context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote(AbstractUsernameFormAuthenticator.ATTEMPTED_USERNAME, username);
        UserModel user = null;
        try {
            List users = context.getSession().users().searchForUserByUserAttributeStream(context.getRealm(), "gsm", username).collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (users != null && users.size() == 1) {
                user = (UserModel) users.get(0);
                logger.info("get the phone number of the user {}: {}",username,user.getAttributes());
                inputData.put("username", Collections.singletonList("clientRole"));
                super.validateUserAndPassword(context,inputData);
            }
        } catch (ModelDuplicateException mde) {
            if (mde.getDuplicateFieldName() != null && mde.getDuplicateFieldName().equals(UserModel.EMAIL)) {
                setDuplicateUserChallenge(context, Errors.EMAIL_IN_USE, Messages.EMAIL_EXISTS, AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
            } else {
                setDuplicateUserChallenge(context, Errors.USERNAME_IN_USE, Messages.USERNAME_EXISTS, AuthenticationFlowError.INVALID_USER);
            }
            return false;
        }

        if (invalidUser(context, user)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!validatePassword(context, user, inputData, false)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!enabledUser(context, user)) {
            return false;
        }

        String rememberMe = inputData.getFirst("rememberMe").toString();
        boolean remember = rememberMe != null && rememberMe.equalsIgnoreCase("on");
        if (remember) {
            context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote(Details.REMEMBER_ME, "true");
            context.getEvent().detail(Details.REMEMBER_ME, "true");
        } else {
            context.getAuthenticationSession().removeAuthNote(Details.REMEMBER_ME);
        }
        context.setUser(user);

        return true;
    }

    private boolean invalidUser(AuthenticationFlowContext context, UserModel user) {
        return true;
    }}
```

and over here is the code for the  factory:

```
public class MobileAuthenticationFactory extends UsernamePasswordFormFactory  {

    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "phone-authenticator";
    public static final GsmAuthenticator SINGLETON = new GsmAuthenticator();

    public static final AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement[] REQUIREMENT_CHOICES = {
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.REQUIRED,
            AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement.DISABLED
    };
    private static final String WEBSITE_URL_PROP_NAME = "custom_website_url";
    /**
     * the provider configuration metadata definition
     */
    private static final List<ProviderConfigProperty> configMetadata;

    static {
        configMetadata = ProviderConfigurationBuilder.create()

                // add the data source name property
                .property()
                .name(WEBSITE_URL_PROP_NAME)
                .type(ProviderConfigProperty.STRING_TYPE)
                .label("Csutom Website URL")
                .defaultValue("https://www.example.com/site")
                .helpText("The base URL of the custom website. Error messages will generate links back to this location.")
                .add()

                .build();
    }

    private String siteURL;

    @Override
    public Authenticator create(KeycloakSession session) {
        System.out.println("GSM authenticator has been created");
        return SINGLETON;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope scope) {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Validates a mobile and password from login form.";
    }
}
```

I have done the deployment to keycloak and it seems it has done successfully, i can see the authenticator in the authentication tab,
so what i have done next is creating a authentication flow and add the custom authenticator, then try the admin api to try get token ,
problem when ever I try to call the api the it return internal error ,

and keycloak logs return the flowing error:

> 2023-06-23 15:30:35,642 ERROR
> [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler]
> (executor-thread-27) Uncaught server error:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: RESTEASY003715: path was null     at
> org.jboss.resteasy.specimpl.ResteasyUriBuilderImpl.path(ResteasyUriBuilderImpl.java:382)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor$Result.getActionUrl(AuthenticationProcessor.java:566)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor$Result.form(AuthenticationProcessor.java:540)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.challenge(UsernamePasswordForm.java:91)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.authenticate(UsernamePasswordForm.java:81)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:445)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:249)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:380)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:271)
> at
> org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:1026)
> at
> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.resourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(TokenEndpoint.java:639)
> at
> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequestInternal(TokenEndpoint.java:223)
> at
> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.access$100(TokenEndpoint.java:131)
> at
> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint$1.runInternal(TokenEndpoint.java:185)
> at
> org.keycloak.common.util.ResponseSessionTask.run(ResponseSessionTask.java:67)
> at
> org.keycloak.common.util.ResponseSessionTask.run(ResponseSessionTask.java:44)
> at
> org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInRetriableTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:299)
> at
> org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.TokenEndpoint.processGrantRequest(TokenEndpoint.java:178)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
> at
> io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.RequestDispatcher.service(RequestDispatcher.java:73)
> at
> io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.dispatch(VertxRequestHandler.java:151)
> at
> io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:82)
> at
> io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.standalone.VertxRequestHandler.handle(VertxRequestHandler.java:42)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:84)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.StaticResourcesRecorder$2.handle(StaticResourcesRecorder.java:71)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:430)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$6.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:408)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:173)
> at
> io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:140)
> at
> org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.integration.web.QuarkusRequestFilter.lambda$createBlockingHandler$0(QuarkusRequestFilter.java:82)
> at
> io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
> at
> org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
> at
> io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

any help would be much appreciated.